# how to bind value in to hidden field

Tags: jquery, autocomplete

below is my code the auto suggestion and every thing is fine 
i need the fromlocationid to store hidden field

(value: item.fromlocationname,
label: item.fromlocationname)

```
  <script type='text/javascript'>//<![CDATA[ 
$(window).load(function(){ 

 var json;

var searchRequest = null;
$("#field").autocomplete({

maxLength: 5,
source: function(request, response) {
    if (searchRequest !== null) {
        searchRequest.abort();
    }
    searchRequest = $.ajax({
        url: 'getfromlo',
        method: 'post',
        dataType: "json",
        data: {term: request.term, json: json},
        success: function(data) {
            searchRequest = null;
            response($.map(data.items, function(item) {
                return {
                    value: item.fromlocationname,
                    label: item.fromlocationname
                };
            }));
        }
    }).fail(function() {
        searchRequest = null;
    });
}
});


});//]]>
```

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking.  What is "the fromlocationid" and what does it mean to "store a hidden field"?  Are you referring to an `input type="hidden"`?  Are you trying to write a value to that input or read a value from that input?  What isn't working in your code?

Comment: value: item.fromlocationid
, label: item.fromlocationname  i need to store the fromlocationid
in to hidden field when user click the fromlocationname

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your comment on the question:

> i need to store the fromlocationid in to hidden field

What is your hidden field?  How do you identify it?  For example, if it looks like this:

```
<input type="hidden" id="myHiddenField" name="myHiddenField" />
```

then you can set its value like this:

```
$('#myHiddenField').val(item.fromlocationid);
```

"Hidden" form fields work just like any other form fields, when using jQuery you use [the `.val()` function](http://api.jquery.com/val/) to read/write their values.

**Edit:** If the value you're reading is in the `item` object, then clearly that object only exists in the scope of the function which declares it:

```
function(item) {
    return {
        value: item.fromlocationname,
        label: item.fromlocationname
    };
}
```

So you might use it here:

```
function(item) {
    $('#myHiddenField').val(item.fromlocationid);
    return {
        value: item.fromlocationname,
        label: item.fromlocationname
    };
}
```

This doesn't seem *entirely* correct, though.  Keep in mind that this function is going to be evaluated many times, once for each `item` in `data.items`.  So you're going to be setting the value of that `input` many times, and afterward it will contain only the value of the last element in the `data.items` array.

So you're probably going to need to put at least *some* thought into the logic of what you're actually trying to accomplish here.  Mechanically as part of the language this is how you would set a value to an `input`.  Logically what you're actually trying to accomplish still isn't clear, you need to handle that.

Comment: <input type="hidden" id="myHiddenField" name="myHiddenField" />   i have a hidden field like above where can i put the code ref my code above $('#myHiddenField').val(item.fromlocationid);

Comment: @user2555935: You'd place the code wherever you need it to be executed.  Any point at which you have the value that you're looking to assign, you can assign that value.  If the value is coming from the `item` object then it looks like the code would need to be in the anonymous `function(item) {}` function that you pass to `.map()`.

Comment: can you pls edit my code with what you have said because i am new to jquery and autocomplete pls help me

Comment: where can i add after                             return {value: item.fromlocationname,label: item.fromlocationname};
     $("#university").val(item.fromlocationid);
alert(item.fromlocationid);

Comment: @user2555935: I've updated the answer to demonstrate.  However, be aware that it's still not clear what you're actually trying to do.  How you set a value on an `input` is pretty straightforward, but where/why you're setting it is up to you.

Comment: @user2555935: No, you don't add things after a `return` statement.  A `return` statement, well, *returns* from the function.  So anything after a `return` statement in the scope of that function would never be executed.

Comment: i got it thanks  for the reply     i have add before return      $("#university").val(item.fromlocationid);
                    return {value: item.fromlocationname,label: item.fromlocationname};